# How to export a part of destructuring assignment?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

```js
export const { a, ...rest } = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
```

In TypeScript, this exports both of `a` and `rest`.
How can I export only `rest`?

Comment: `const { a, ...rest } = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }; export rest;`

Comment: TypeScript says `TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.`

Comment: Sorry, it should be `export { rest };`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To export it as default:

```
// data.js
const { a, ...rest } = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
export default rest;
```

```
// main.js
import rest from "./data";
console.log(rest);  // { b: 2, c: 3 }
```

To export as a named export:

```
// data.js
const { a, ...rest } = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
export { rest };
```

```
// main.js
import { rest } from "./data";
console.log( rest ); // { b: 2, c: 3 }
```